# How to set fan speed in Windows, preferably via command line?

Tags: windows, fan, cooling

I simply want to set my fan speed constant with a value from 0% to 100% (or the equivalent). I can do this on Linux via `echo <0 to 255> > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1`. I can also reset it back to automatic by echoing -1.

Now I want to do the same thing on Windows. I tried SpeedFan, but apparently it doesn't detect support from the motherboard - I don't get the `PWM_X` attribute or w/e that you need to set to manual. Not to mention it hangs on startup after reading info about my video card.

I also tried RWeverything, however I'm not sure what I need to edit and I don't want to risk blowing up my computer.

I assume that since Linux can let me control my fan, Windows should be able to do it too. Moreover, if Linux can detect where and what to write to the system, there should be a way for me to do it, be it via software or manually, on Windows as well.

I am once again asking for your administrative support.

Answer (score 1):

The other day I needed something like this and made my own solution. I'm probably late for you, but leaving this here for posterity.

[FanSet](https://github.com/michyprima/FanSet) uses OpenHardwareMonitorLib to set your motherboard fans easily via the commandline.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106819)

Comment: @Toto the problem is you can't really do it without using third party software that you can't even fully compile on your own. Controlling fans on Windows requires a EV-signed Ring0 driver so the best I can do is link him a software that he can call from the command line.

Comment: @michyprima I just noticed this and tried using it but I got an empty output. I guess it's not recognizing my fans? (laptop is from 2015, currently running Win10). That being said, I reference the code and attempt to do something myself in the future, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FanControl:
https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1099996-fancontrol-my-take-on-a-speedfan-replacement/page/1/

FanControl doesn't accept command-line parameters, so it's not a perfect match for your request, but perhaps you can use it to solve your problem.  Assuming it understands your motherboard hardware, I think you could use it to set a constant fan speed of your choosing by constructing a constant control curve.  However, you hinted that being able to reset the fan back to automatic (by command-line) is another one of your requirements, but you didn't literally say it is.

At least two commenters have requested adding a command-line feature to FanControl.  Perhaps if enough people request it, the developer will implement it. (This is a hint to you to request it too.)  I imagine it wouldn't take much time for the dev to implement it.

One of the commenters suggested an alternative that would be easier to implement than command-line parameters: treat a text file like a temperature sensor.  Instead of using a command-line to set the fan speed, an app would overwrite the text file, and FanControl would periodically read the file.

Comment: It would help to know the brand and model of your PC, but regardless, you can try ThinkPad Fan Control (even if your PC is not a Lenovo): https://thinkwiki.de/TPFanControl (download links are at the bottom of the page, don't worry). It works wonders on Lenovo laptops where fan speed and temperature management is anything but an exact science... You can edit the TPFanControl.ini file in Programs under TP Fan Control to your liking, in Notepad (admin); just make sure to close the program first. I know it works on Sony and Asus laptops without failing.